# Have radio buttons for each row of a query result

Tags: php, html, button, radio-button

I am having issues with creating radio buttons for each query result. For each line returned I want to have an extra column that consists of 2 radio buttons. the user should only be able to select 1 of these 2 buttons. Right now I have the column of radio buttons but the user can only select 1 of each radio button, not 1 for each result of the query. I hope that makes sense.

Should I be even using radio buttons? Or should I use check boxes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>games</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<select name="weekNo">
<option value="1">week 1</option>
<option value="2">week 2</option>
<option value="3">week 3</option>
<option value="4">week 4</option>
<option value="5">week 5</option>
<option value="6">week 6</option>
<option value="7">week 7</option>
<option value="8">week 8</option>
<option value="9">week 9</option>
<option value="10">week 10</option>
<option value="11">week 11</option>
<option value="12">week 12</option>
<option value="13">week 13</option>
<option value="14">week 14</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Games" />
</form>
<br>
<hr>
<?php

 $conn = 
 or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //submit button pressed
{
$query=NULL; //prevent compile error

$weekNum = $_POST['weekNo'];

    $query = "SELECT a.game_no AS game_number, a.home AS home_team,
            homeTeam.wins AS home_wins, homeTeam.losses AS home_losses,
            a.away AS away_team, awayTeam.wins AS away_wins,
            awayTeam.losses AS away_losses, a.spread AS spread
            FROM weekly_stats AS a
            INNER JOIN team AS homeTeam ON a.home = homeTeam.name
            INNER JOIN team AS awayTeam ON a.away = awayTeam.name
            WHERE a.week_no = $weekNum";
 $result = pg_query($query) or die ('Query failed: ' .pg_last_error());

    $query2 = "SELECT week_no, game_no FROM weekly_stats";
    $result2 = pg_query($query2) or die ('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

 // Printing results in HTML
 echo "<br>There are " . pg_num_rows($result) . " records found.\n<p></p>\n";
 echo "<table border=1>\n\t<tr>\n";

 for($i=0; $i<pg_num_fields($result); $i++)
 {
 echo "\t\t<th>" . pg_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>\n";
 }
 echo "\t\t<th>Picks</th>\n";

  echo "\t</tr>\n";

 while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))
 {

    echo "\t<tr>\n";

    foreach ($line as $col_value)
    {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }

    echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks\" value=\"home\">Home
  <input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks\" value=\"away\">Away</td>";


 echo "\t</tr>\n";
 }

 echo "</table>\n";
 // Free resultset
 pg_free_result($result);
 }
 // Closing connection
 pg_close($conn);

 ?> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You need to create unique names per rows, which can be done by creating an array name, ie. `name=\"picks[{$col_value}]\"`. `{$col_value}` could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

The input name is the same on all of your radio buttons so the web browser is assuming they all answer the same question (Home or Away for ALL records) rather than a set of questions (Home or Away for EACH record).  You need to differentiate the names for each pair of radio buttons for each row.

```
$row=0;
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "\t<tr>\n";

    foreach ($line as $col_value)
    {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }

    echo "<td>"
        ."<label>Home <input type='radio' name='picks[$row]' value='home'></label>"
        ."<label>Away <input type='radio' name='picks[$row]' value='away'></label>"
        ."</td>";

    echo "\t</tr>\n";
    $row++;
}
```

On the server side it will interpret the submission as an array.  The $row variable above could be a unique index or ID for each row rather than simply a counter as I demonstrated.

Comment: Thanks mate will accept answer when I can. Thanks for explaining it aswell

Comment: One more question @jasonCG. Is there anyway to incorporate words with these radio buttons? For the first button I want them to say HOME and the next AWAY. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'd suggest using the label tag with the "for" attribute.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: even if answer is correct `echo "\t<tr>\n";` is horrible style of coding

Comment: I didn't clean up much of his original code.  After I answered he removed his code from the question...

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons with the same names cannot be selected simultaneously. Radio buttons for each query should have unique names but names for two buttons of the same query should have the same name.

The code should be modified to:-

`echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks[$row_number]\" value=\"home\">Home
  <input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks[$row_number]\" value=\"away\">Away</td>";`